# Not able to catch exception sending SMS with Twilio in plugin

Tags: plugin-development

Not sure if this is the best place to post, but since it's a Craft 3 plugin I'll give it a shot.

```
foreach ($numbers as $number){
    $number = $twilio->lookups->v1->phoneNumbers($user->mobil)->fetch(['countryCode' => 'NO'])->phoneNumber;

    try {
        // Send SMS
        $twilio->messages->create(
            $number,
            [
                'from' => $settings->twilioNumber,
                'body' => $request->post('body')
            ]
        );
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        continue; // Continue (loop) to next number as this one failed/is invalid.
    }
}
```

In short, whenever a `$number` is invalid, execution stops giving `Twilio\Exceptions\RestException [HTTP 404] Unable to fetch record: The requested resource /PhoneNumbers/"the-invalid-number" was not found`.

It seems that the `catch` is never reached.

Note that I have tried replacing `\Exception` with the following to no avail.

```
use Twilio\Exceptions\ConfigurationException;
use Twilio\Exceptions\DeserializeException;
use Twilio\Exceptions\EnvironmentException;
use Twilio\Exceptions\HttpException;
use Twilio\Exceptions\RestException;
use Twilio\Exceptions\TwimlException;
```

Regardless, I thought `\Exception` would catch any exception?

Edit: Here's the solution.

```
try {
    // Validate the number
    $number = $twilio->lookups->v1->phoneNumbers($user->mobil)->fetch(['countryCode' => 'NO'])->phoneNumber;

    // Send SMS
    $twilio->messages->create(
        $number,
        [
            'from' => $settings->twilioNumber,
            'body' => $request->post('body')
        ]
    );
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Number is invalid; continue to next number
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is thrown before you enter your catch block during this line

```
 $number = $twilio->lookups->v1->phoneNumbers($user->mobil)->fetch(['countryCode' => 'NO'])->phoneNumber;
```

That's why it can't be cached. Move it into the same block and handle every single possible exception that can be thrown accordingly or via generic `\Exception` class